# Como hacer dos condiciones dentro de un DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito lograr que se cumpla dos condiciones dentro de un `DECODE` en Oracle.

Lo que tengo hecho de mi `DECODE` es lo siguiente:

```
DECODE (CODE, 'PR', 'Muestra 1',
              'ES', 'Muestra 2',
```

Para que se cumplan las dos condiciones de mi `DECODE` necesito:

- Que el `CODE` sea `'PO'`
- Que su `EQUIV` sea igual a `85`

En la documentación oficial de Oracle no encontré algo similar a lo que requiero [Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las compraraciones con decode son uno a uno. Mejor usa una expresión `CASE`:

```
CASE 
  WHEN CODE='PR' 
    THEN 'El título de '
  WHEN CODE='ES' 
    THEN 'El diploma de '
  WHEN CODE='PO' AND EQUIV = 85
    THEN 'con 85’
END
```

Con `CASE` anidado:

```
CASE CODE
  WHEN 'PR' THEN 'El título de '
  WHEN 'ES' THEN 'El diploma de '
  WHEN 'PO' THEN CASE EQUIV
                   WHEN 85 THEN 'con 85'
                   ELSE 'sin 85'
                 END
END
```

Similarmente puedes anidar decode:

```
decode( CODE
      , 'PR', 'El título de '
      , 'ES', 'El diploma de '
      , 'PO', decode( EQUIV
                    , 85, 'con 85'
                    , 'sin 85'
                    )
      )
```

O cualquier combinación de las anteriores.